# Unable to catch an SQL exception

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a Database class:

```
<?php

namespace Database\MySQL;

class Database
{
    function __construct(){

        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

        try {
            $this->Connection = new mysqli(
                "", // Testing with no host
                "", // Testing with no user
                "", // ... no password
                ""  // and no DB name
            );
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
...
?>
```

But instead of a getting an exception, I get a Fatal error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No database selected' in Database.php`.

I have tried the same thing with a simple query:

```
try {
    $this->Connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf87'"); //utf87 just for test
}
catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    throw $e;
}
```

And I still get `Fatal error: Uncaught exception`.

Comment: Does your Database class have namespace?

Comment: @sectus, actually, yes. But I do `new \mysqli` and have tried `catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e)` just to be sure.

Comment: Wait. ... what do you mean by  `throw $e;` ?

Comment: @sectus It doesn't really matter. Even if I use `die("Error");` instead `throw $e;`, I should get any output from withing the catch block. But instead `catch { ... }` is completely ignored.

Comment: @Nordenheim , try one more time to catch `\mysqli_sql_exception`. And do not retrhow it.

Comment: @sectus, you were right >.< Please post an answer, I'll add namespace to question

Comment: I am glad to help :^ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are `catch`ing the exception, but then just `throw`ing it again without `catch`ing it.

If you replace `throw $e;` with `echo "Caught the exception";`, you will see that your script is catching the exception. But because you throw it again, it will result in an error unless you have a higher-level `try`/`catch` block or a global exception handler.

Also, as many have pointed out in the comments, you need to be careful of namespaces. You need to use a `use` statement or refer to `\mysqli_sql_exception`.

Comment: Nope, not true. I went for `catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { die("ERROR"); }` and the fatal error is still the same.

Comment: Please try it with `\mysqli_sql_exception` and verify that the line where the exception occurs is actually in your `try` block. It sounds very much like a namespace problem and/or you're simply not including all relevant code in the `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: P.S. Regardless of any other issues, I can 100% guarantee that simply throwing the exception again will cause a fatal error without a higher-level exception handler.

Comment: yeah, I feel really silly at times like this. It **is** solved by `\mysqli_sql_exception` and it was a namespace problem.